# Rspec tests fail in Namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec2

I've just converted some existing rails tests to rspec, and now the tests that are in a namespace fail.

I.e. in the example below, AccountController spec passes, while the ChildrenController fails with the following error:

```
in `load_missing_constant': Expected /.../app/controllers/admin/children_controller.rb to define Admin::ChildrenController (LoadError)
```

app/controllers/account_controller.rb

```
class AccountController < ApplicationController
```

spec/controllers/account_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe AccountController do
  #...
end
```

app/controllers/admin/children_controller.rb

```
class Admin::ChildrenController < ApplicationController
```

spec/controllers/admin/children_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Admin::ChildrenController do  
   include ::ControllerHelper 
   #... 
end
```

I'm using

- ruby-1.9.2-p0
- Rails 3.0.3
- rspec 2.3.0

I've tried playing with the namespace definitions, but no luck so far - any ideas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting answer in case anyone stumbles over this another time!

In the end I fixed it by flattening the specs like following:

```
app>controllers>admin>children_controller.rb
class Admin::ChildrenController < ApplicationController

spec>controllers>children_controller_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe Admin::ChildrenController do
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution:

by defining the class as a string it will load normally:

```
# children_controller_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe "Admin::ChildrenController" do  
  # -something-
end
```

this will work in the spec/controller/admin directory

edit: doesnt work in 2.10.x

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and was not willing to place the tests in a lower directory. In my case it was Spork that was messing things up.

To be precise:

```
Spork.each_run do
  ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
end
```

I placed a checker if spork is running, else you should ignore this line.

```
Spork.each_run do
  if /spork/i =~ $0 || RSpec.configuration.drb?
    ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm up to date on everything and `RSpec.configuration.drb?` comes back true via spork and rspec w/o spork.

So I used the same check I have in test.rb for cache_classes which is:
`if /spork/i =~ $0 || ENV['DRB'] == 'true'`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it in the following way:

Before:

```
# app/controllers/admin/awards_controller.rb:
class Admin::AwardsController < ApplicationController

# spec/controllers/admin/awards_controller_spec.rb:
require 'spec_helper'

describe Admin::AwardsController do
```

Running rspec gave me:

```
/Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@xxxx/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:503:in `load_missing_constant': Expected /Volumes/untitled/xxxx/app/controllers/admin/awards_controller.rb to define Admin::AwardsController (LoadError)
(stacktrace...)
```

After:

```
# spec/controllers/admin/awards_controller_spec.rb:
require 'spec_helper'
load "#{Rails.root}/app/controllers/admin/awards_controller.rb"

describe Admin::AwardsController do
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep controller under separate folder, but you have to use 
require File.dirname(**FILE**) + '/../../spec_helper'
instead of just require 'spec_helper'